# Visual Studio Code does not attach debugger to multi processes in python using pool map

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-multiprocessing

Hi I am trying to debug multi processes in python.
This below is a portion of where I run multi-processes using Pool

```
pool = Pool(num_half_logical_cpus)
pool_result_dict = pool.starmap(process_batches, lstListSets)
```

However, I can't hit any breakpoints.
Can anyone guide me to hit those breakpoints I set up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this option to launch.json will let you debug multiple processes.

```
"subProcess": true,
```

Then it will hit the breakpoint then you are able to select which process you want to step through (F10). There will be a list of processes at the lower-left sub-window.

Comment: Please forgive this question if it is dumb, but where is that launch.json file? I am using Visual Studio Community, and there is no launch.json file within my project directory or the Visual Studio installation directory. Every mention I can find online regarding either this error or that file seems to be specific to Visual Studio Code, rather than Visual Studio Community. And I'd prefer to not post a new, nearly-identical question that would just confuse other people searching for the Visual Studio Code answer.

Comment: @user3685427 [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Visual Studio (Community)](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) are 2 completely different IDEs. The question was specifically asked for VS Code. The mentioned file resides in `.vscode/launch.json` in the root of a project in VS Code.

Answer (score 4):

Click on "Run and Debug" tab.

Then click "create a launch.json file."

[image]

Then click on "Python".

[image]

Then click on "Python File" configuration.

[image]

VSCode will create a "launch.json" file for you.
At this point you will need to add `"subProcess": true,` as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60529923/6121065

[image]

And you are good to go.
Now you may debug your code.
You may need to tweak the configurations where needed.