# Unable to debug multiprocessing Python code in Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, python-multiprocessing, visual-studio-2022

As per the title, I'm unable to debug Python multiprocessing code in Visual Studio Community 2022.

In the accepted answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515935/visual-studio-code-does-not-attach-debugger-to-multi-processes-in-python-using-p), it is suggested to add the option `"subProcess": true,` to the launch.json file, however in my project's vs folder there is no launch.vs.json file (that in my understanding is the equivalent file in the community version of visual studio) to be found (or any .json file by the way), and I've been unable to find it anywhere or generate it. I've tried for several hours and I'm completely lost; it seems like all the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) about it points to the launch.vs.json file in the vs folder which I don't have.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: The linked question refers to "Visual Studio Code" which is a completely separate and independent product from "Visual Studio".

Comment: @Woodford Yes, I know. That's why I'm asking for Visual Studio 2022, maybe I have been unclear in the question. I'll try to explain myself better: the documentation I've read (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) is all about a launch.vs.json file in the vs folder, so I thought it would have the same use as the launch.json of the Visual Studio Code one.

Comment: Sitting with the same issue, could you resolve it?

Comment: @Sagariouz unfortunately not.